# C# Multithread, which performs the best?

Tags: c#, web-services, parallel-processing

I'm currently writting an application that make a huge lot of call to slow webservices (I had no say in that pattern) that produce little output.
I'd like to make like 100 parallel calls (I know real parallelism can only go as far as you have cores).
But I was wondering if they were performance differences between different approach.

I'm hesitating between:

- Using Task.Factory.StartNew in a loop.
- Using Parallel.For.
- Using BackgroundWorker.
- Using AsyncCallback.
- ...Others?

My main goal, is to have as many webservices calls being started as quickly as possible.
How should I proceed?

Comment: Thought of a threadpool?

Comment: Async is the way to go, if you can use .Net 4.5. Because it uses I/O completion ports where possible it reduces the number of threads in use drastically. Threads are hugely expensive, so this is much better.

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: As Matthew Watson said. Async is the way to go. It's designed to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Austin, it is really not that simple as I've got no control/monitor of the webservices. Actually those web services are even supposed (according to their developers) to run super fast. Yet they're a bottleneck so I want to loose as little time as possible when calling them (at worst, I'll be able to prove, they're the one slowing my solution down).

Comment: @Serge Note that the webservice itself may sent its response *very* quickly after receives its request and still be your bottleneck.  Network communication is in itself very slow; often the slowest aspect of an application.  It may not be anyone's "fault".

Comment: @Servy Our own bandwidth and ping are fine, and when the web services developer chose that pattern they were promising lightning fast speed (through Internet).

Comment: @Serge even with "lightning fast speed", you cannot avoid delays from the network. A remote call that returns immediately takes at least 50 ms in very good conditions. That does not look like a lot, but compared to the execution time of a standard program, it feels like an eternity.

Comment: So, when referencing a web service, I should let C# auto generate Async methods and prioritly use them (xxxCompleted event + xxxAsync method)? I'm guessing that auto generated code use I/O event as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your advices I used Async (with I/O event) while I was previously using TLP.
Async really does outperform Sync + Task usage.

I can now launches 100 requests (almost?) at the same time and if the longest running one takes 5 seconds, the whole process will only last 7 seconds while when using Sync + TLP it took me like 70 seconds.

In conclusion, (auto generated) Async is really the way to go when consuming a lot of webservices.

Thanks to you all.

Oh and by the way, this would not be possible without:

```
<connectionManagement>
  <add address="*" maxconnection="100" />
</connectionManagement>
```

Comment: I wonder why some people mark this question as "not a real question". I described a clear scenario (many web services calls in parallel) and asked the best suited approach.

Answer (score 8):

From a performance standpoint it's unlikely to matter.  As you yourself have described, the bottleneck in your program is a network call to a slow performing web service.  *That* will be the bottleneck.  Any differences in how long it takes you to spin up new threads or manage them is unlikely to matter at all due to how much they will be overshadowed by the network interaction.

You should use the model/framework that you are most comfortable with, and that will most effectively allow you to write code that you know is correct.  It's also important to note that you don't actually need to use multiple threads on your machine at all.  You can send a number of asynchronous requests to the web service all from the same thread, and even handle all of the callbacks in the same thread.  Parallelizing the sending of requests is unlikely to have any meaningful performance impact.  Because of this you don't really need to use *any* of the frameworks that you have described, although the Task Parallel Library is actually highly effective at managing asynchronous operations *even when those operations don't represent work in another thread*.  You don't *need* it, but it's certainly capable of helping.